# Strapi return error code 400 on user registeration, when email verification is on

Tags: authentication, registration, strapi

- I have installed the send grid module for strapi.

  > npm i strapi-provider-email-sendgrid
- configured the email plugin
  [image: ![enter image description here]
- Role and permissions setting
  [image]
- But still whenever I register a user Error code 400 is return, also No mail is being sent.

  > POST /auth/local/register

[image]

- However the **user is created** in strapi's Users content type
  [image]
- Console screenshot.

  [image: List item]

Help me in dealing with it!!

Answer (score 3):

The error management of the email plugin is not good, we have to change it!

This error is probably provided by this [code line](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/21a14ee737ff782f0655e76ee121465d0d5bb667/packages/strapi-provider-email-sendgrid/lib/index.js#L56-L57)

To got the correct error, I suggest you to add a `console.log` of the `err` in your `strapi-provider-email-sendgrid` `node_module` directly.

I know it's not good to do that but it will be the only way to know the error that you have.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.
I `console.log` the `err`.
This the output
`{ messages: [ { id: 'Auth.form.error.email.invalid' } ] }`.

I actually find a solution to this. I over-write the **Auth.js** file in `\extensions\users-permissions\controllers`. I will post a complete solution to it :).

_But still, the problem is not actually resolved. It is just a side-way._

Comment: Oops @Jim LAURIE, I actually `console.log` the `err` in the *Auth.js* file.

Here is the `err` console.log from `strapi-provider-email-sendgrid` `node_module`

 `code: 401,
  message: 'Unauthorized',
  response:
   { headers:
      { server: 'nginx',
        date: 'Thu, 26 Dec 2019 16:13:44 GMT',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
...some other stuff as well
       },
     body: { errors:  [ { message:
        'The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked',
       field: null,
       help: null } ] } } }`

Comment: Is your sendgrid privilege are correct? (config, token and blablabla...)

Comment: yes they are. I am able to send mail by replacing strapi mail code with the official code from sendgird 
[I used the code available over here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendgrid), which mean config, token etc are correct.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issues with the AWS SES email provider from Strapi, so I'll leave my resolution here in case someone googles their way into this question in the future.

That error message is actually thrown by the Sendgrid Strapi email provider in line 58 (https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/dae9cfa415881f17ebb95d9ea3887c6a0ae0dca6/packages/strapi-provider-email-sendgrid/lib/index.js#L58).

There's a catch that will swallow exceptions thrown by the Sendgrid library and throw instead this generic message. Here are your options to figure out what the actual error is:

1. Debug the provider by attaching to the running NodeJS process
2. Add some console.log statements to the `node_modules/strapi-provider-email-sendgrid/lib/index.js` file inside the catch and inspect your standard output
3. Modify the call to reject inside the catch to return the actual `error.message` string. This might require looking into how Strapi will handle errors thrown inside controllers to make sure it doesn't end up getting lost in the I18N midlleware or other extension points.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with strapi/sendgrid. The problem was the fact that the sender was not a verified email in sendgrid.

Step to fix:

- I looked for : id: `'Auth.form.error.email.invalid'` in my node_modules.
- Then, I logged the error

```
   sendgrid.send(msg, function(err) {
     if (err) {
      console.log(err.response.body.errors)     
      reject([{ messages: [{ id: 'Auth.form.error.email.invalid' }] }]);
     } else {
       resolve();
   }
```

- I had the following message inside the error : "The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity requirements"
- So, i went to sendgrid and verified my sender's emails. And it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

It says in your messages.id "Auth.form.error.email.invalid".

From Sendgrid's website: "An invalid email occurs when you attempt to send email to an address that is formatted in a manner that does not meet internet email format standards or the email does not exist at the recipient's mail server... If the recipient server checks the address and doesn't find it, they will send back a 550 bounce to say that this is an invalid email address."
https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/invalid-emails/

Does that email address actually exist? Try testing with your personal email account.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I checked my sendgrid dashboard, and it shows 
Request =0(_I guess, which mean sendgrid did not reject it. It was just that they did not receive any request from strapi_). I have also tested it with my own email account, the result is the same.

Any further suggestions?